# Conditional merge and transformation of data in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

I have two data frames, and I want to create new columns in frame 1 using properties from frame 2

frame 1

```
    Name
    alice
    bob
    carol
```

frame 2

```
    Name  Type  Value
    alice lower 1
    alice upper 2
    bob   equal 42
    carol lower 0
```

desired result

frame 1

```
    Name   Lower Upper
    alice      1     2
    bob       42    42
    carol      0    NA
```

Hence, the common column of both frames is Name. You can use Name to look up bounds (of a variable), which are specified in the second frame. Frame 1 lists each name exactly once. Frame 2 might have one or two entries per frame, which might either specify a lower or an upper bound (or both at a time if the type is equal). We do not need to have both bounds for each variable, one of the bounds can stay empty. I would like to have a frame that lists the range of each variable. I see how I can do that with for-loops over the columns, but that does not seem to be in the pandas spirit. Do you have any suggestions for a compact solution? :-)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not looking for a merge, but rather a `pivot`.

```
(df2[df2['Name'].isin(df1['Name'])]
 .pivot('Name', 'Type', 'Value')
 .reset_index()
)
```

But this doesn't handle the special 'equal' case.

For this, you can use a little trick. Replace 'equal' by a list with the other two values and `explode` to create the two rows.

```
(df2[df2['Name'].isin(df1['Name'])]
 .assign(Type=lambda d: d['Type'].map(lambda x: {'equal': ['lower', 'upper']}.get(x,x)))
 .explode('Type')
 .pivot('Name', 'Type', 'Value')
 .reset_index()
 .convert_dtypes()
)
```

Output:

```
    Name  lower  upper
0  alice      1      2
1    bob     42     42
2  carol      0   <NA>
```

Comment: It doesn't take care of the `'equal`' values.

Comment: Right, I have to say I had not seen it. You can fill using `where`, I'll update when I have a chance

Comment: @Alex867 fixed it (I used a different approach)

Comment: That was super-helpful, thanks a lot! In hindsight, I could probably have figured out the first part, but no way I would have found the second part in any reasonable time without your help. Now I know some new functionality to read up upon and investigate.

Comment: @T-Mo there are other strategies for the second part. One could check if there is a value in "equal" after pivoting, set the other columns to this value if True, and delete "equal", but I found this hack nice ;)